# Eloquent - Get latest date and insert the result to another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

We have 2 tables

**Titles**

```
+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| id   | title                                | subs_updated | created_at          |
+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
|  104 | movie 1                              |              | 2014-11-11 12:08:28 |
|  129 | movie 2                              |              | 2014-11-11 12:08:29 |
+------+--------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Subs**

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| id |  label   | title_id | subs    | created_at          |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| 13 | English  |      104 | English | 2014-11-12 05:05:39 |
| 15 | Italian  |      104 | Italian | 2014-11-12 05:25:00 |
| 16 | Dutch    |      104 | Dutch   | 2014-11-13 05:40:51 |
| 18 | Arabic   |      129 | Arabic  | 2014-11-12 06:05:28 |
| 19 | Arabic   |      129 | Arabic  | 2014-11-12 06:07:23 |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

**In the SubsController i have :**

```
public function attach()
{
    $input = Input::except('_token');

    if ( ! Input::get('label') || ! Input::get('subs')) {
        return Response::json(trans('subs::main.fillAllRequiredFields'), 400);
    }

    if ( ! isset($input['title_id']))
    {
        return Response::json(trans('dash.somethingWrong'), 500);
    }

    else
    {
        $this->model->fill($input)->save();
    }

    return Response::json($this->model, 201);
}
```

**Subs Model**

```
<?php

class Link extends Entity {

    public $table = 'subs';

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function title()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Title');
    }
}
```

1. I want to find the latest sub by created date (created_at) for a title (title_id) in subs table.
2. Insert that result (date) to titles table => title (id) => subs_updated
3. Use that query along with the above attach() function

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you please add the code of your `Sub` and `Title` model to the question?

Comment: Hey Lucas, Ive posted the subs model. The title model is tooo big to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I analyzed your problem correctly you want to update `subs_updated` every time a new sub gets created. This can be nicely done using [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#events)

In your `Sub` model, override `boot()` to register the event:

```
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    self::created(function($sub){
        $title = $sub->title;
        if( ! is_null($title)){
            $title->subs_updated = $sub->created_at;
            $title->save();
        }
    });
}
```

If you wanted to update `subs_updated` every time you update or create the sub you can use the `saved` event:

```
self::saved(function($sub){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::statement(
   'update titles set subs_updated = 
       (select max(created_at) from subs where title_id = ?)
    where id = ?', 
    [$titleId, $titleId]
);
```

or, assuming `Title hasMany Sub` relation, more *Eloquent* way:

```
$subsUpdated = $title->subs()->max('created_at');
$title->update(['subs_updated' => $subsUpdated]);
```

Comment: Any ideas how to implement this with the attach() function above? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you follow Laravel's naming conventions and have setup the appropriate models:

```
$latestSub = Sub::select('created_at')->where('title_id', 104)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
Title::where('id', 104)->update(array(
    'subs_updated'  => $latestSub->created_at
));
```

If you don't have models setup, simply use the same code, but use query builder instead of Eloquent

```
$latestSub = DB::table('subs')->select('created_at')->where('title_id', 104)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
DB::table('titles')->where('id', 104)->update(array(
    'subs_updated'  => $latestSub->created_at
));
```

Comment: Hey Dave, can you please let me know how to implement this query with the attach() function above?